# USB and LM7805 both to power Arduino

Tags: power, usb, relay

I have high current usage For my circuit as you can see below ([link](https://github.com/Startup-Data/UN-Hakim-PCR/tree/main/Arduino/Temperature)):

[image]

I like to power Arduino when it is not connected to PC by **USB Connection**, So I want to add **one external power supply** and connect it's **GND** And **5V** to Arduino **GND** And **5V** pins.

So with this new circuit, I have **two power supply** for **Arduino uno** as you can see below: :

1-USB Connection to PC

2- Powering the Arduino by External Power Supply and LM7805

[image]

So I Asked here about connecting two power supply for Arduino (external power supply and PC USB Connection) and check this circuit Safeness for USB Port of PC or the Arduino.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. Should work

Comment: All you have done there is replicate the voltage regulator that is already on the Arduino itself. Seems a bit pointless to me. If you want higher current 5V then you should consider either a 5V supply (USB charger) or a switching regulator instead of linear. Otherwise you're really not achieving anything useful.

Comment: @Dave_Newton, I have updated the Question and make it clearer. Also based of the comments, i guess the Circuit would working.

Comment: Thanks, @Majenko. the question is When i have **USB connection** and **the second power supply**, can I connect **GND And 5V** pins of the **new power supply** and the **Arduino pins** ( **GND and 5V** Pins) to each others?

Comment: Sure you can. Just like the internal regulator is.